# Automatically send a value from input to output with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Recently I’m working on an Online Shopping Site and in one of the parts of my site I used this code :

```
<button>buy</button>
<input value="Variable"/>
<div class="output"></div>
```

The main goal of this code is this :

I have some input gates `<input value="Variable"/>` , when user click on one button `<button>buy</button>` , “ php and $.get() ” sends the value to input gates .

Also I want when the values are in input gates , these values also be sent to output by “jQuery” . 
I used this code for doing that :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("input").change(function(){
        $('div.output').text($(this).val());
    });

});
```

But it didn’t work .

the problem is that this code only works when I set the values manually . but when the values are set with “php and $.get()” , it won’t work . the `.change(function(){});` won’t work .

So I give it up and used this code instead :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('*').hover(function(){

       $('div.output').text(  $("input").val()  );

    }); 

});
```

So what do u guys suggest I should do ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call `change` when the input value changes using JS then use:

```
$("input").trigger('change');
```

Comment: would you please explain more ? @Sourabh-

Comment: @DaninNamiranian As I understand, you are trying to update `input` programatically and you expect it to call the `change` event, is that correct? If not then I guess I did not get your question.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to understand most of the question(but I am not sure I do). But from what I understand, you should be doing this.

```
$.get( "whatever/url", function( data ) {
  $('div.output').text(data);
});
```

This way you will be able to send data from the server and accordingly update the value of input.